# How know if a Firebase list is void?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use the ChildEventListener following the doc. During the data loading, I just make visible a progress drawable in a listview

- If the list is not empty, then I hide/null the progress view.
- If the list is void, I display "no item"

  ```
  // Get a reference to our posts
  Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts");

  ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
      // Retrieve new posts as they are added to the database
      @Override
      public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
          BlogPost newPost = snapshot.getValue(BlogPost.class);
          System.out.println("Author: " + newPost.getAuthor());
          System.out.println("Title: " + newPost.getTitle());
      }

      //... ChildEventListener also defines onChildChanged, onChildRemoved,
      //    onChildMoved and onCanceled, covered in later sections.
  });
  ```

With `ref.addValueEventListener`we can just check that the `datasnapshot`is null to know it.

How do know that the list is void ? Is it possible ? Without first checking with `addValueEventListener` ?

Comment: Are you looking for `DataSnapshot.hasChildren()`? Docs say "Indicates whether this snapshot has any children"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only know that there are no items in the list by attaching a ValueEventListener.

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasChildren()) {
            System.out.println("List is empty");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that usually if you call `addChildEventListener()`, you'll end up storing the items in some internal storage such as a `List`. You can also simply check if that internal storage is empty (after `onChildRemoved()` is triggered) and print the message there.

Comment: My usage is not too much the case of removing items, but more that I do not know, before adding the listener if there is something inside the path or not. It case of empty list, this is ok, but with a list of 1000 objects, I will download one time the object pull by adding addEventValueListener, and then a second time by addChildEventListener. Not so efficient.

Comment: A `ChildEventListener` and a `ValueEventListener` on the same query or ref, will download the same data at the same time. The only difference is in the events/callbacks that they fire.  If you don't want to download the data to see if anything exists, consider adding a separate `dataExists` node in your JSON tree that you set to `true` when you first add a node.